# string already written in input dialog box in java swing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, dialog

i want a string already written in the input dialog box text field when this dialog box appear.

```
String filename = jLabel6.getText();
String fname=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter File Name");

String dir=fc.getCurrentDirectory().toString();
dir = dir+"\\"+fname+"_crypt.txt";
```

here i want the string in variable filename appear in text box of dialog box , so one can accept this file name or edit if want.
i am writing code in netbeans.
is there any option to do this? or i should leave this thought??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use a [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)?

As always, the API is your best friend: [showInputDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, Object initialSelectionValue)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Look for a function that takes an argument for the default value.

Comment: the file in fc is obtained from jFileChooser. i want this for saving data to a new file

Comment: @Nitkt: then you can use JFileChooser **again** to choose a new file to save to. This is nothing but simple common sense. 1+ to Kevin.

Comment: i want to create a new file to save the content in the same directory with different name. but i think jFileChooser is used to choose a file, not to create.?? no way to give a value to input dialog box? which a user can edit

Comment: @Nitkt Again, the API is your best friend: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html which links to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html which shows you how to *open* a file.

Comment: @kevin, ok this is easy, thanks to your suggestion to look into API.

    public static String showInputDialog(Object message,
                     Object initialSelectionValue)
just have to edit `String fname=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter File Name");` to

    `String fname=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter File Name",filename);`

this initialize textfield of input dialog box with string in filename.

Comment: True. However, it sounds like what you're looking for is a JFileChooser, which has a showOpenDialog() function. Up to you.